# How to insert line break in innerHTML

Tags: ajax, innerhtml, line-breaks

I am using ajax to update some form fields.

One of the fields is the following

```
<td id='alarms_id'></td>
```

In file update.js.erb, I have the following :

```
alert('<% concat @alarms %>')
document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '<% concat @alarms %>'
```

In the controller, if I do the following (for testing purposes)

```
@alarms = "Hello World!"
```

all will work fine, I see the alert popup window, and I see the field showing "Hello World!" message. But in my real application, I want all alarms to be in separate lines, so I tried this:

```
@alarms = "Hello \n World!"
```

but then I don't see the alert message and my field is not updated (no Hello World message shows up). I tried Firefox and Safari and none worked for me.

Anyone understands what am I doing wrong, and how can I get the "Hello World!" message to show in 2 separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Ruby on Rails**, you can do it in several ways:

Use `html_safe` to mark your HTML variable:

```
@alarms = "Hello <br/> World!".html_safe
document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = 'concat <%= @alarms %>';
```

Or use `html_safe` to display your HTML variable:

```
@alarms = "Hello <br/> World!"
document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = 'concat <%= @alarms.html_safe %>';
```

Or use `raw` to display your HTML variable:

```
@alarms = "Hello <br/> World!"
document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = 'concat <%=raw @alarms %>';
```

Notice that the `alert()` function in JavaScript does not understand HTML code, so you cannot use it to display your HTML variable as is.

Comment: Thanks Racil. I tried this and it returns this error "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `raw' for nil:NilClass):"

Comment: @rh4games I assumed that you're using MVC, are you not? What version? I think `Html.Raw()` was added in MVC 3. I will updated my answer so you can do it with pure ASP.Net.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I tried document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '<% concat alarms %>' and it printed "Hello <br> World!"

Comment: @rh4games I've just tried it and it prints correctly on two lines. Please pay attention to the `=` sign, it is `<%=` not `<%`.

Comment: Thanks again Racil. I did copy/paste of your answer into my js and added @alarms to get the variable right. The alert message displays 'concat Hello &lt;br&gt; World!' and in alert_id field it displays 'concat Hello <br> World!' in one line.

Comment: @rh4games Something is going wrong. Just for testing, copy/paste this and tell me the result: `document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '1<br/>2<br/><%= "3 <br/> 4" %>';`

Comment: Suggestion: These results hinge on the template engine. Do tag the question with "Rails" or whatever.

Comment: @Jerry101 Yes, you're right. I asked him if he was using ASP.Net/MVC and what version, but he didn't answer. If he's not using ASP.Net, then this whole discussion is pointless. rh4games?

Comment: @Jerry101 and Racil : thanks you for your help. I'm using Ruby on Rails and MVC. The server is now unavailable (maintenance). I'll try your suggestions later on.

Comment: @RacilHilan : I tried your suggestion and it printed "1" on the 1st line, "2" on the 2nd line and "3 <br/> 4" on the 3rd line. the alert popup window displayed only one line "1<br/>2<br/>3 &lt;br/&gt; 4"

Comment: @RacilHilan : but when I set my variable to "Hello<br/>World!", it's all printed as is on one line only.

Comment: @rh4games You should've mentioned **Ruby on Rails** in your question instead of wasting your time and ours on solutions in other languages. All this time I was giving you solutions in ASP.Net. I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: @RacilHilan : thanks a bunch for your support and I apologize for not being more clear from the beginning.
All 3 solutions worked for me with slight changes. These are the working solutions:
1) alarms = "Hello<br/>World!".html_safe and document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '<% concat alarms %>' (notice there is no "=" sign)
2) alarms = "Hello<br/>World!" and document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '<% concat alarms.html_safe %>' (notice there is no "=" sign)
3) alarms = "Hello<br/>World!" and document.getElementById("alarms_id").innerHTML = '<%= raw alarms %>'

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you write a line break like this: `<br/>` not `\n`.

Comment: Thanks Jerry101. I tried that and it simply printed <br/> in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@alarms = "Hello \n World!"` have you tried `@alarms = "Hello <br> World!"`?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I tried that and it simply printed <br> in the text field.